# Sum of Multiple Cell Macro codes

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Since I am new to Macro, Can I have a Solution to my queries, I  was trying to create Simple Macro Code for getting the sum of multiple cell in a sheet and the range will be on a different cell. 
`=SUM(B5:E5,G5:H5)`  this is the formula and the cell is Y5 and sheet6.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have a look at the [WorksheetFunction.Sum method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.sum) and try something on your own first please. This is not a free code writing service. That means we cannot provide you a macro, but we can help you to improve/fix your own macro if you have tried something.

Comment: Actually there is no macro needed for this. You just can use `=SUM(INDIRECT(Y5))` and write `B5:E5,G5:H5` into cell Y5.